# Implementing bootstrap modal dialog in angular7

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I was stuck for a while on implementing a simple bootstrap modal dialog box and found pieces of the answer in about 10 different pages. Considering I couldn't find the answer quickly nor clearly I thought I'd share my solution to help others. (first answer below)

In case you have to add multiple types of bootstrap widgets I suggest taking a look at (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

Comment: A much better option would be to ditch jQuery and the bootstrap JavaScript, and use ng-bootstrap: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: I added the reference in the question for people who want to add many different types of widgets

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the *src/index.html* I changed the content of the body tag to:

```html
 <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
    </script>
</body>
```

In the component, which calls the modal, I have in the template:

```html
<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="showModal()">
  Open modal
</button>
<app-modal></app-modal>
```

And in the typescript component

```js
    showModal(): void {   
        this.displayService.setShowModal(true); 
        // communication to show the modal, I use a behaviour subject from a service layer here
    }
```

I build a separate component for the modal, in the template I have

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="hideModal()">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="sendModal()" >Send</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="hideModal()">Close</button>

        <!-- this button is hidden, used to close from typescript -->
        <button type="button" id="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal" style="display: none">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the Typescript component I have

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    // This lets me use jquery
    declare var $: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-modal',
      templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
    })
    export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
      showModal():void {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
      }
      sendModal(): void {
        //do something here
        this.hideModal();
      }
      hideModal():void {
        document.getElementById('close-modal').click();
      }
    }
```

Now the modal dialog works, has a send function where some additional logic can be, and a hide function to close the modal from typescript

Comment: why not use this to close the modal? 
    `hideModal():void {
        $("#paymentModal").modal('hide');
      }`

Comment: Good question, it's been a while since I checked this but as far as I remember just doing the hide doesn't trigger the data-dismiss="modal", which means you modal is prefilled with the previous data when you reopen it. I know I tried it the way you suggested, but had a reason to switch to the way I'm doing it now. It could be that it's only be needed if you had some sort of form in there...